# HDF5 write python array memoryerror,

Tags: python, hdf5, large-data

I want to write HDF5 format as 512x424(1channel) image database and multi-label in python (anaconda library) for image regression.
However, I have some error which is happened when memory allocation as array type.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

cols = 512
rows = 424
channel = 1
total_image = sum(1 for line in open(data_label_list))
total_size = total_image*rows*cols
f_train = open(data_label_list)
lines = f_train.readlines()

data = np.empty((total_image, channel, cols, rows))
multi_label = np.empty((total_image, 1))
```

==========================================

```
data = np.empty((total_image, channel, cols, rows))
"MemoryError"
```

Can I solve this error for large scale database?

add source code :

```
cnt = 0
for line in lines:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    list_line = line.split(' ')
    im = Image.open(list_line[0])
    row, col = im.size
    pixels = im.load()
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            data[cnt, 0,  i, j] = pixels[i, j]
     multi_label[cnt, 0] = list_line[1]
     multi_label[cnt, 1] = list_line[2]
     cnt += 1
```

Thanks,

Comment: What are the values you passing to `empty`.  You haven't gotten to the h5py part yet.

Comment: I add a source code. data[] = pixel[] <-- due to this part, I have to allocate a array

Comment: No I need to know the size of the array that is too big.  Also does your code work for a smaller test case?

Comment: Ah, total_image = 42327, It is quite big.

Comment: find some other waythat doesn't require one big array.